# How to generate a bearer token from azure ad with user credentials

Tags: c#, azure

I have a .net core API and JWT token authentication code is added in the application. My problem is how can I generate the bearer token from any application so that I can authenticate the request. I am not able to generate the bearer token.

I have tried lots of options like from Postman GetNewAccessToken. Its asks for Single sign-on but after sign-in open the Microsoft office website in a new window. How can I get bearer token from Postman?

**Is there is any way for getting the bearer token from C# application using users's credentials or using single sign on?**

[image]

[image]

I need a bearer token just to authenticate my request.

Answer (score 1):

Open up your F12 developer tools in your browser, look up an authenticated request and have a look at the Authentication header. It has a current version of a Bearer token.

For instance:

- Go to the [Graph Explorer preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview)
- Sign in to Graph Explorer (top **left**)
- Open up F12 developer tools
- Run the Me query
- See the request to `/me` in the Network tab
- Inspect the request headers and find the Authorization header

[image: Authorization header from Graph Explorer - Preview]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the token programmatically, you should check out Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview and more specifically [MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet)